# Accurately measure performance of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

What is the best way to accurately measure the performance (time to complete) of a stored procedure?

I’m about to start an attempt to optimize a monster stored procedure, and in order to correctly determine if my tweaks have any effect, I need something to compare the before and after.

My ideas so far:

- Looking a query execution time SQL Management Studio: Not very accurate, but very convenient.
- Adding timers in the stored procedure and printing the elapsed time: Adding debug code like that stinks.
- Using the SQL Server Profiler, adding filters to target just my stored procedure. This is my best option so far.

Any other options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Profiler is the most reliable method. You can also use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` but these don't include the full impact of scalar UDFs.

You can also turn on the "include client statistics" option in SSMS to get an overview of the performance of the last 10 runs.

Comment: yep, you capture IO, CPU, Duration etc

Comment: The "include client statistics" option is extremely helpful too, I'm going to go with that and the Profiler. Thanks. :)

Comment: i didn't even know about 'include client statistics' in SSMS, very useful

Answer (score 9):

There's lots of detailed performance information in the DMV `dm_exec_query_stats`

```
DECLARE @procname VARCHAR(255)
SET @procname = 'your proc name'

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats WHERE st.objectid = OBJECT_ID(@procname)
```

This will give you cumulative performance data and execution counts per cached statement.

You can use `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to reset the counters (don't run this in a production system, since will purge all the cached query plans).

You can get the query plans for each statement by extending this query:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
        ((CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) [sub_statement]
        ,*, CONVERT(XML, tqp.query_plan)
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS APPLY
     sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st CROSS APPLY
     sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) qp CROSS APPLY
     sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset  ) tqp
WHERE st.objectid = OBJECT_ID(@procname)
ORDER BY statement_start_offset, execution_count
```

This will give you pointers about which parts of the SP are performing badly, and - if you include the execution plans - why.

Comment: Dynamic Management Views are new to me, but it certainly looks like something I should check out. Thanks!

Comment: Very good query for retrieving statistics for procedures performance - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible improvement on your timers/debug option is to store the results in a table. In this way you can slice-and-dice the resulting timing data with SQL queries rather than just visually parsing your debug output.

Comment: I disagree. Run Profiler on a server other than the database server and store the results of the trace in a file. That way you do not load the SQL Server and affect the trace results (assuming you are trying to be accurate).

Comment: That's pretty clever, and may even justify littering the sp with some debug code. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to ensure that you are performing fair tests i.e. comparing like with like. Consider running your tests using a cold cache in order to force your stored procedure execution to be served from the IO Subsystem each time you perform your tests.

Take a look at the system stored procedures [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) and [DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178529.aspx)